# How to check if a CDK overlay (OverlayRef) is currently open, from another component?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-cdk

I have component A where I create an OverlayRef with ComponentPortal.

In another component B, I need to do something only when no overlays are open. So in component B I need to check wether an overlay is open or not.

Is there a native way to check if an OverlayRef is open from another component? Or do I have to create some logic to check it? (like extending OverlayRef with a service)